# State field misaligned in billing form - Magento 2 checkout page

Tags: magento2, frontend, design, knockoutjs

The state field coming top of the billing form in checkout payment page.

The issue coming only in chrome browser when I refresh the page more than three times.  I hope that it is because of cache issue.

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Thanks,
Karol M[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I am not able to comment yet.

This is an open bug reported to Magento. Please see the following link : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9420